# Javascript .innerHTML but excluding inner div

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

Considering I have this `div`:

```html
<div class="ResCheckIn">
  <div class="ResDtlLabel">
    Check-in
   </div>
   Thursday, October 18, 2018
</div>
```

I simply want to get the string `"Thursday, October 18, 2018"`, so excluding the inner `div`.
If I try with `.innerHMTML`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.ResCheckIn').innerHTML;
```

It returns everything in `.ResCheckIn`, including the inner `div` with class `"ResDtlLabel"`, so this:

```html
<div class="ResDtlLabel tSmall tLight">
    Check-in</div>
Thursday, October 11, 2018
```

And ideally I would love to do that without using jQuery.

Comment: you only want the textnodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is iterating through `childNodes` and filtering the `textNodes`. The following function gets all the `textNode` children and stores their values in an array.

```
const nodes = document.querySelector('.ResCheckIn').childNodes;
const texts = [].reduce.call(nodes, function(ret, el) {
  if ( el.nodeType === 3 ) {
    ret.push(el.nodeValue.trim());
  }
  return ret;
}, []);
```

`texts` is an array of `textNode`s contents.

Comment: you might want to use `Node.TEXT_NODE` instead of 3 for better readability.

Comment: Or directly `el.nodeName === "#text"`

Answer (score 2):

Not a very innovative answer but if you are looking for simple solution try this

```
var content = document.querySelector(".ResCheckIn").innerHTML;
    content = content.split('</div>');
    if(content[1]){
        content = content[1].trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ResCheckIn')[0].textContent
```

Comment: This will return all the text

Answer (score 1):

**Using jQuery**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var html=$('.ResCheckIn').html();
    var parsedText=$.parseHTML(html);
     $.each(parsedText, (i, el) => {
          if (el.nodeType === 3) {
          if(el.nodeValue.trim()!=""){              
             console.log(el.nodeValue);
             alert(el.nodeValue);
           }
          }
     });
  });
</script>
<div class="ResCheckIn">
  <div class="ResDtlLabel">
    Check-in
   </div>
   Thursday, October 18, 2018
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "content of node". for better understanding about this please look into this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp).

There are multiple ways you can achieve your result. below is one of way,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var parentnode = document.querySelectorAll('.ResCheckIn')[0];
  console.log($(parentnode).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
  }).text().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ResCheckIn">
  <div class="ResDtlLabel">
    Check-in
  </div>
  Thursday, October 18, 2018
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Example container.
let container = document.getElementsByClassName('ResCheckIn')[0];

// Loop over child elements and remove them. Note that this is ES6 syntax and may not yet be supported in all browsers.
Array.from(container.children).forEach(em => { 
    em.parentElement.removeChild(em);
});

console.log(container.textContent);
```

Just a simple example. If you remove only all child `elements` (and not `nodes`) from an`HTMLElement` (like `container` in this example), the text nodes are skipped and you are left with the text only.