# In Javascript, how can I querySelector to get the innerHTML excluding one of the inner sibling divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors, queryselector

I have the following html:

```
<body>
    <span class="comment">
        EXAMPLES:
        <p><i>Example 1</i> - <a href="https://example.com/1">https://example.com/1</a> - Jan 2020 (2 comments)</p>
        <p><i>Example 2</i> - <a href="https://example.com/2">https://example.com/2</a> - Jun 2022 (13 comments)</p>
        <div class="reply"><p><u><a href="reply?id=12323" rel="nofollow">reply</a></u></p></div>
        <p><i>Example 3</i> - <a href="https://example.com/3">https://example.com/3</a> - Apr 2023 (33 comments)</p>
    </span>
</body>
```

I am trying to get the `innerHTML` of the `.comment` class except the `.reply` div.

Note that the `.reply` class is not guaranteed to be the last.

Basically, I want to get just:

```
EXAMPLES:
<p><i>Example 1</i> - <a href="https://example.com/1">https://example.com/1</a> - Jan 2020 (2 comments)</p>
<p><i>Example 2</i> - <a href="https://example.com/2">https://example.com/2</a> - Jun 2022 (13 comments)</p>
<p><i>Example 3</i> - <a href="https://example.com/3">https://example.com/3</a> - Apr 2023 (33 comments)</p>
```

I am unable to figure out how I can exclude one of the sibling children.

I know I can get the children except the `.reply` class using the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll(`.comment > :not(.reply)`)
```

But this isn't the `innerHTML`. It's a `NodeList`:

[image]

Is there a way to get a new combined element from this `NodeList` on which I can then call `innerHTML` on?

I found a slight similar question here:

[Javascript .innerHTML but excluding inner div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404551/javascript-innerhtml-but-excluding-inner-div)

but that question is about extracting a specific string and solutions seem ugly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a deep [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) of the `comment` node and [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) the `reply` node before retrieving the `innerHTML`:

```js
var comment = document.querySelector(".comment").cloneNode(true);
comment.querySelector(".reply").remove();
console.log(comment.innerHTML);
```

```html
<span class="comment">
  EXAMPLES:
  <p><i>Example 1</i> - <a href="https://example.com/1">https://example.com/1</a> - Jan 2020 (2 comments)</p>
  <p><i>Example 2</i> - <a href="https://example.com/2">https://example.com/2</a> - Jun 2022 (13 comments)</p>
  <div class="reply"><p><font size="1"><u><a href="reply?id=12323" rel="nofollow">reply</a></u></font></p></div>
  <p><i>Example 3</i> - <a href="https://example.com/3">https://example.com/3</a> - Apr 2023 (33 comments)</p>
</span>
```

Note I added the missing closing `</font>` tag to your example. Without that, the unmatched opening `<font>` would remain in the `innerHTML`.

Comment: Ah, that's genius. Didn't know the `cloneNode` could be used in this way! As for the missing `</font>`, yea, I removed it from the question after I posted it. Thank you.